# Change the datatype of a property of an mvc model that has a default value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to change the data type of a particular column in my model that has a default value setting.

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage ="Please enter customer's last name")]
    [Display(Name = "Last name")]
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
    public string Lastname { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Please enter customer's first name")]
    [Display(Name = "First name")]
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "float")]
    public double Points { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Id Type Presented")]
    public int IdTypeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("IdTypeId")]
    [Display(Name = "Id Type")]
    public virtual IdType IdType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Status")]
    public int StatusTypeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("StatusTypeId")]
    [Display(Name = "Status")]
    public virtual StatusType StatusType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Id Number")]
    [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Id number is required for verification")]
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
    public string IdNumber { get; set; }

    public Customer()
    {
        this.Lastname = "";
        this.Firstname = "";
        this.IdNumber = "";
    }
}
```

The 3 columns in the constructor above are preventing me from updating the database because it says:

```
The object 'DF__Customers__IdNum__31EC6D26' is dependent on column 'IdNumber'.
ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN IdNumber failed because one or more objects access this column.
```

Here is the generated migration script

```
public partial class setdatatypestovarcharincustomerstablewhereapplicable : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {

        AlterColumn("dbo.Customers", "Lastname", c => c.String(maxLength: 50, unicode: false));
        AlterColumn("dbo.Customers", "Firstname", c => c.String(maxLength: 50, unicode: false));
        AlterColumn("dbo.Customers", "IdNumber", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 20, unicode: false));
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        AlterColumn("dbo.Customers", "IdNumber", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 20));
        AlterColumn("dbo.Customers", "Firstname", c => c.String(maxLength: 50));
        AlterColumn("dbo.Customers", "Lastname", c => c.String(maxLength: 50));
    }
}
```

How can I do this? Can I drop the constraint inside the migration script then recreate it?

Thanks

Comment: first i was going to say just remove the constructor. Also you can do default values at the end of the properties value like so `public string Lastname { get; set; } = "";` But really you already answered your own question, for a question that has no possible relevance to anyone else. So why not just delete it instead?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did. Set the defaultValue inside the migration script.

```
public override void Up()
{            
    AlterColumn("dbo.Customers", "Lastname", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 50, unicode: false, defaultValue: ""));
    AlterColumn("dbo.Customers", "Firstname", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 50, unicode: false, defaultValue: ""));
    AlterColumn("dbo.Customers", "IdNumber", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 20, unicode: false, defaultValue: ""));
}
```